# How can I send an input in a page to another page with hyperfiddle Electric via using query url

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, electric-clojure

I use [Electric Clojure](https://github.com/hyperfiddle/electric) for creating web applications. I want to get an input from the client and redirect to another page with url query parameter and show the input redirected page.

I tried Ring module in the Clojure script. But it didn't work. After that, I tried Compojure and it didn't work neither. Furthermore, I can use `hyperfiddle.history/link` function for calling new page functions but I cannot add any parameter which can send to new page.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.